# How to get my KDE4 back in Kubuntu 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, kde, plasma, kde5

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04.
KDE5 Plasma looks pretty but it brings too many bugs and glitches such that I want my KDE4 back.

How can I install KDE4 instead of KDE5?

Comment: That does not work.

Comment: In pure theory it'd be possible. I am not sure the amount of resources (especially time) needed is feasible. Do you use KUbuntu for everyday work?